# Google Docs - user's icons

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

We use Google Docs and some of the nicknames inside the sheets of the people that are logged in the document are colourful and others are faded... 
Some users are clear and some are blurred...

I thought it is because some users are active and some are not at the moment but seems this is not the reason. Does anybody know what is the difference? I hope my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

- **Anonymous Animal** - active user which is in the sheet/doc and it's not logged in or it's  not added in permissions
- **Faded Anonymous Animal** - user which has loaded sheet/doc in a tab of the browser but the tab is not active and the user is not logged in or it's  not added in permissions
- **Icon with the letter** - user which is logged in and active in the sheet/doc (but didn't upload a picture to the profile)
- **Faded Icon with the letter** - logged in user that has opened the sheet/doc in the browser but it's in a different tab of the browser
- **Picture Icon** - logged in user which is present at the moment on the sheet/doc and uploaded a profile picture
- **Faded Picture Icon** - logged in but doing something else in some other tab of the browser

**note:** there is (could be) up to 1 minute delay from not faded to faded state